# The assembly does not contain a public invokable method with [JSInvokableAttribute]

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor, blazor-jsinterop

We use Blazor WebAssembly and I want to call an non-static method in my Index.razor-File by JavaScript.

**JavaScript:**

```
(function () {

    // keydown event
    window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('MyBlazorWebAssemblyApp.Client', 'MyMethod');
    });
})();
```

**Index.razor:**

```
@page "/"
@inject HttpClient Http

@code {
    
    // [...]
    
    [JSInvokable]
    public async Task MyMethod()
    {
        var lResponse = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<object>("Controller/Action");
    }
}
```

When I execute the code by an keydown, then the developer tools in Microsoft Edge shows me the following error:

> blazor.webassembly.js:1 System.ArgumentException: The assembly
> 'MyBlazorWebAssemblyApp.Client' does not contain a public invokable
> method with [JSInvokableAttribute("MyMethod")].

When I replace the attribute `[JSInvokable]` by `[JSInvokableAttribute("MyMethod")]` then the same error appears.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-3.1#instance-method-call

Comment: What happens if you just use MyBlazorWebAssemblyApp i.e. remove the .Client from the app assembly argument?

Comment: @Mark3308: System.ArgumentException: There is no loaded assembly with the name 'MyBlazorWebAssemblyApp'.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Got it working now by my self. Here is the code:

**JavaScript:**

```
var GLOBAL = {};
GLOBAL.DotNetReference = null;
GLOBAL.SetDotnetReference = function (pDotNetReference) {
    GLOBAL.DotNetReference = pDotNetReference;
};

(function () {

    // keydown event
    window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        GLOBAL.DotNetReference.invokeMethodAsync('MyMethod');
    });
})();
```

**Index.razor:**

```
@page "/"
@inject HttpClient Http

@code {
    
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var lDotNetReference = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
        JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("GLOBAL.SetDotnetReference", lDotNetReference);
    }
    
    // [...]
    
    [JSInvokable("MyMethod")]
    public async Task MyMethod()
    {
        var lResponse = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<object>("Controller/Action");
    }
}
```

Comment: One question here, how does GLOBAL.SetDotnetReference get dotnetreference  ?

Comment: @KshitijAnilRangari it's created in the `OnInitializedAsync`

Comment: @Simon but your code has a problem when use in Foreach, already call last item.

Comment: Excellent Question and Answer - this also works within OnAfterRenderAsync, and was great for me since I also needed it for a non static method in a simple single page application :).

Comment: Thanks, this is the only thing that's worked (besides making the method static) after hours of trying. However I have another problem now. My Blazor code that's called from JS is on a separate razor page/component. When I navigate to it, I get this error:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find 'GLOBAL.SetDotnetReference' ('GLOBAL' was undefined).
Then if I refresh the page, the error goes away and it works. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

If you check out the Microsoft documentation at the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-3.1#instance-method-call

This differs from your example in the following ways:

Your JavaScript appears to be trying to call a static .NET method.

Your C# code is not a static method.

Answer (score 2):

You must mention `<<Namespace>>.<<TypeName>>.<<MethodName>>`

> Important: C# Method must static

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", async function (e) {
        await DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('MyBlazorWebAssemblyApp.Client', 'MyMethod');
});
```

[#40110 issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/40110#issuecomment-1034618920)